# is it possible to convert bmp to png in python using only windows resources not PIL or pillow?

Tags: python, image, winapi, png, bmp

Here's what I have so far but I keep running into errors

```
import win32com.client

def bmp_to_png_winapi(bmp_filepath, png_filepath):
    shimgvw = win32com.client.Dispatch("WIA.ImageFile")
    shimgvw.LoadFile(bmp_filepath)
    png_format_id = "{B96B3CAF-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}"
    shimgvw.SaveAs(png_filepath, png_format_id)
```

It couldn't find WIA.ImageFile: "AttributeError: WIA.ImageFile.SaveAs".

I want to use the windows API because I'm hoping it would be the fastest since it won't rely on a third party library like Pillow.  If you know of the fastest way to convert bmp to png, I'd appreciate any help.  I tried PIL and it was about .11secs, I also tried opencv, and it was about half that time.  I wonder how fast it would be if I just used win32 imports instead.

Comment: What about using [this](https://www.win2pdf.com/doc/command-line-bmp-to-png.html) with combination of `subprocess`?

Comment: You can use [Windows Imaging Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wic/-wic-creating-encoder#tiff-encoding-example) to read and write image data in an application.

Comment: Yeah I tried that but I kept on getting errors with trying to access WIC via pywin32.  Are you sure its even possible via the pywin32 library?

Comment: The Windows Imaging Component is based on COM. It is my understanding that pywin32 comes with COM support (presumably under `win32com.client`).